# Wrong check with Strings

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and can't understand, why this check has the output false:

```
 // $answer would be a Global Variable
 my $answer;

 // the rest is in a sub scope
 print "Do you want to proceed? (Y/N)";
 $answer = uc <STDIN>;

 if($answer eq "Y"){
     print "success";
 } else {
     print "why";
 }
```

Comment: ```Scalar found where operator expected at x.pl line 1, near "// $answer"
 (Missing operator before  $answer?)
Bareword found where operator expected at x.pl line 1, near "$answer would"
 (Missing operator before would?)
Bareword found where operator expected at x.pl line 4, near "// the"
 (Missing operator before the?)
syntax error at x.pl line 1, near "// $answer "
syntax error at x.pl line 4, near "// the rest "
Illegal declaration of subroutine main::scope at x.pl line 5.```

Comment: Hello @Quentin Obviously it doesn't work. I set the comments for the STACK OVERFLOW user to //. In Perl it would be #. I typed it like that, so everyone will understand, that they aren't in the same scope.

Comment: Write Perl comments in your Perl code! People can understand them to mean "this is a comment" and can copy/paste your code to test it!

Comment: @Quentin Alright got it, thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what the value of `$answer` actually is:

```
print "---$answer---";
```

It outputs

```
---Y
---
```

So it isn't equal to `"Y"`, it is equal to `"Y\n"`.

Use [`chomp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) on the string.